# Best way to reduce consumed bandwith when using struts tags to diplays html?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts-1

I'm using Struts 1.3, and using StringBuilder to form a html body in the tag to display some lists in the website. I'm trying to figure out the best way to optimize this, since this is using most of the bandwidth, because some lists are very long and I'm sending the whole HTML structure inside the tag.

I didn't actually program this, but I'm in charge of reducing the consumed bandwith, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, and I'm open to any suggestions.

For a brief explanation, I have a .jsp with a tag in it and it just writes the whole html body.

```
<html>
    <prototype:myTag/>
</html>
```

And inside the myTag comes the whole HTML structure. JSON is the only thing that comes to my mind to reduce the bandwith consumption, but I'm sure there must be plenty of other things.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A good way to reduce bandwidth in HTML is to *ensure [HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) is used*. Most other [significant] reductions come from simply *sending less data* - not a different generic structure of data; HTML, JSON, and XML will have "equivalent" compressed sizes (within a few percentage) for the same data, as the duplicate tags are readily compressible text.

Comment: yes, compressing your content should be the first thing to try. Best of all, in most cases it can be enabled via server configuration, without modifying your code.

Comment: Alright, I take a look at that, thanks!